# Table inside table without two border space in CSS

Tags: css

I want create a table inside a table data. But i am seeing the gap between the outer table and inner table which i dont want. I am not able to attach the image

My Code:

```
<table class="clearfix sureIQTable scanoTable borderGray TableBottomBorder" id="softTissue">

    <tr>
    <th nowrap="nowrap" style= "width:1px; background-color: #88A4BB;"></th>
    <th nowrap="nowrap"  style="width:87px; background-color: #88A4BB;"></th>
    <th class="textLeft" style="font-size:12px" colspan="17">
    <span class="textLeft"><xsl:value-of select="ScanModeParam/comment"/></span>
    </th>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th class="textLeft" colspan="3" style="background-color: #88A4BB;vertical-align:top;font-size:15px;font-weight:normal; white-space: nowrap;"><img src="images/GG_Helical.png" alt=""/><br></br>                                                            

        <td>
        <table width="100%">
        <tr >
        <th class="textCenter width30px" style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold">Start</th>
        <th class="textCenter width100px" style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="ScanModeParam/StartTime/@DisplayName"/></th>
        <th class="textCenter width100px" style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="ScanModeParam/WaitTime/@DisplayName"/></th>
    <th class="textCenter width100px" style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold">Start Position(mm)</th>
    <th class="textCenter width100px" style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="ScanModeParam/Range/@DisplayName"/></th>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Could anyone please help me

Thanks

Comment: Definate codepen/jsfiddle needed.

Comment: Post HTML code (not XSL code for generating it) and CSS code that actually demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

Comment: I tried bt not working. But if i use position:absolute, then there is no gap, but from right side the width is squeezed. Any help?

Comment: Hi Samuele, The code base is very lengthy. I will post a custom code. But my question is simple. I am creating a table inside a row as below.<table>
 <tr>
  
 </tr>
 <td>
  <table> 
   <tr>
   </tr>
  </table>
 <td>
</table> By default the css properies is there is a gap between the inner table and the outer row. My requirement is i dont want this gap.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it?

To make no space between cells Use border-collapse: collapse;

For CSS

```
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px; //It is for IE 
}
```

Comment: I tried bt not working. But if i use position:absolute, then there is no gap, but from right side the width is squeezed. Any help?

Comment: can you say wht s your o/p now? and, wht s yur expected o/p?